# How to get the South East Pointing Vine Leaf (&#128603;) to show up on Safari on iOS?

Tags: html, unicode

How I can code this ornamental character into HTML to show up on Safari on iOS?

`&#128603;`

I've tried its hex form but to no avail:

`&#x1F65B;`

It shows up fine on Firefox on Windows.

It's called the South East Pointing Vine Leaf. Is there some other encoding that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character you're referring to,  (U+1F65B), is kind of new addition to the Unicode standard, so not all browsers and platforms might support it natively. So I recommend you to use SVG rather than Unicode.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 -622 1005 749.99999"   width="335" height="250" >
  <g  transform="translate(-51,-349)">
    <path d="m 323,233 c 283,0 411,-197 590,-197 67,0 85,23 85,50 0,18 -8,46 -45,46 -136,0 -336,-405 -504,-405 -79,0 -189,90 -189,207 0,67 38,120 95,120 65,0 106,-70 106,-83 0,-2 -1,-3 -3,-3 -7,0 -10,5 -32,5 -58,0 -118,-36 -118,-87 0,-34 25,-56 60,-56 154,0 343,404 499,402 75,-1 189,-95 189,-210 0,-48 -22,-90 -96,-90 C 810,-68 659,125 379,119 234,116 132,32 132,-67 c 0,-56 30,-77 30,-85 0,-2 -2,-4 -5,-4 -17,0 -106,61 -106,170 0,103 83,219 272,219 z M 299,477 C 469,477 653,156 729,81 l -59,25 c -22,31 -192,264 -323,264 -46,0 -68,-24 -68,-51 0,-17 9,-24 9,-27 0,-1 -1,-3 -4,-3 -18,0 -82,51 -82,109 0,40 28,79 97,79 z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```